# linux newbie Rootsystem

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 18.04

It seems impossible to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my new computer with Windows 10. I don´t understand how to deal with the root system failure. Ubuntu crashes every time I get to that step. No partitions is showed.

I want to delete Windows and install Ubuntu. How can I accomplish this?

Problem solved: When i switch to AHCI mode in UEFI and not RIDE i could install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean it doesn't show you the option for "erase disk and install ubuntu" and it crashes before that.

You can simply delete windows first and then run the installer.

1. Insert the Ubuntu Live CD,DVD or USB. go to "Try it without installing"
2. Connect to the wifi on the ubuntu live.
3. Install gparted "sudo apt-get install gparted"
4. Remove Windows partition (Right Click Delete).
   5.Try running the installer now after reboot.

Comment: Nope, i never get that option."erase and install". I get a enpty window tha says "rootsystem fail" and krasch.
that was my idea too but I can't delete windows.

Comment: Is Gparted not letting you delete the partition ? can you show the error log opening Gparted using terminal or just show me the error message ?

Comment: Yes that's correct! Not gnome disks or gparted find the harddrive/partition only the USB drive. I don´t know how to show you the log but the program gparted only shows the usb drive and that´s the same in the installation procedure, only the USB drive is showing. the error message are in swedish and saying "no rotfilesystem is defined" "correct this from the partition menu"

Answer (score 0):

see https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 For a complete manual on installing ubuntu. You need a proper formatted usb. You can use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by Windows "Hybrid Sleep" because Windows still locking drives in UEFI.
There are two possible solutions:

1. (If you have access to Windows) **FULL Windows shutdown**

*On Windows* - open `cmd` and then run command: `shutdown /s /f /t 0`

2. (No access to Windows) **Disk repartitioning**

Run Ubuntu in Live mode and then format whole drive. You can use built-in:
`gnome-disks` tool or install `gparted` and then format.

`sudo apt install gparted`

Comment: no change, linux can´t find any partitions/harddrive. "no rotfilesystem is defined" "correct it from the partition meny"